# Mod_rewrite to redirect all requests

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This should be simple, but I'm stuck. I want to redirect all requests for example.com/something to example.com/index.php?code=something, except example.com/add-new which should go to example.com/index.php?page=add-new.

I've done the latter as

```
RewriteRule ^add-new$ index.php/?page=add-new [L]
```

and it works, but I can't figure out how to do the former. I want to redirect everything after the final slash, that is after example.com to index.php?code=

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, in a way...

My script uses 5 character code and through trial and error I found that this works

```
RewriteRule ^(.{5})$ index.php/?code=$1 [L]
```

Now every URL that contains 5 characters at the end gets redirected where it should, or at least I haven't found a problem with it yet. Redirecting only 5 character strings is not what I wanted, but it does the job for now.

Here's my complete .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^add-new$ index.php/?page=add-new [L]
RewriteRule ^(.{5})$ index.php/?code=$1 [L]
```